# Making a JPanel and inside add multiple JPanels

Tags: java, swing, awt, jpanel, layout-manager

I need to build in swing a screen that is something like this image. I have a main panel and in that panel I need to add multiple columns 2 vertical columns and 3 horizontal. This columns are Jpanels. I tried to use GridLayout but I did not succeeded.

[image]

Comment: Try border layout for this

Comment: Border layout is not useful for this design because in the regions I can add only one component.

Comment: @AlexGo But you could use a `BorderLayout` as the base.  The two side panels could exit in there own panel and the two center panels in another (3 panels all together), which means you get East, Center and West..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very rarly will a single layout manager do everything you want.  You want to start using compound layout managers where you can/need.

This example uses both a `GridLayout` and a `GridBagLayout`

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class BadLayout21 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BadLayout21();
    }

    public BadLayout21() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {

            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JPanel leftPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 0, 0, 4));
            leftPane.add(createPane(Color.RED));
            leftPane.add(createPane(Color.RED));

            JPanel leftMiddlePanel = createPane(Color.BLUE);
            JPanel rightMiddlePanel = createPane(Color.BLUE);

            JPanel rightPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 0, 0, 4));
            rightPane.add(createPane(Color.GREEN));
            rightPane.add(createPane(Color.GREEN));

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 0, 0);
            add(leftPane, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 3;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(20, 0, 0, 20);
            add(rightPane, gbc);

            gbc.weightx = 0;
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 10);
            add(leftMiddlePanel, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 2;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0);
            add(rightMiddlePanel, gbc);

        }

        protected JPanel createPane(Color color) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 25));
            panel.setBackground(color);
            return panel;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be difficult to place all the panels directly in one big panel. Multiple solutions are possible. Like dividing the the main panel in four seperate (vertical) panels and add the final panels to those four sub-panels. Or as freak suggested, start with a border layout, and first create a left-subpanel, center-subpanel and right-subpanel, each with their own layout managers. And in those sub-panels you can place your final panels.

Although the precise purpose or goal is a little fuzzy for me right now, I hope you can use my suggesten.